# What is the best way to deal with big amounts of data and arrays?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jpa

I am working on a java project that deals with large amounts of data. More specifically, it deals with a lot of vector objects. Each vector object contains the following attributes:

```
public class Vector{
    private final int dimension;
    private short[] sparseOffsets;
    private boolean isSparse;
    private float[] coordinates;

    ...
}
```

The arrays on this vector object can become really big (we are talking size 10,000 each) and we deal with millions of vectors at a time. Obviously, I've been running out of memory due to the quantity of these vector objects and the size of their arrays. I tried serializing them but after a week of waiting, the code was still serializing these vector objects.

I am thinking of implementing a MySQL Database with JPA. First question I have is, would this be an ideal path to follow to deal with these large amounts of data?

Second question is, how would I go about storing these big arrays on the database?

I found an example about an employee object that contains an array of employee courses and uses a one to many relationship. It looks like this:
[image]

So basically I would be transforming those arrays into arraylists and using the @ElementCollection mark. Would this be a good way to go about storing these big arrays on the database?

Comment: Some questions about your question: Are you currently storing all these vector arrays in memory? How does a new vector get written into memory? Are you working on all of them at once, or do you only need to work on a subset of them at a time?

Comment: Yes currently storing all these vector objects which contain the arrays (updated sample code, see above) in memory by instantiation of the vector class. Working with a subset of them at a time, reason why I thought having a db might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single 'best' way here; but the whole point of databases is to deal with large amounts of data, and read into memory only what you currently need to work on.

Don't expect a completely tutorial in this post, as that is impossible, but I'd start with three tables: one base table holding scalar information like 'isSparse' and 'dimension', but most importantly, and 'id' for that vector. Then two other tables, which provide the association of 'id' -> 'sparseOffset' and 'id' -> 'coordinates'.

I'm a database rookie, so corrections by experts are welcome, but hopefully this will give you a starting point.

Comment: Yes, thank you Lars. I appreciate your response. I am a database rookie as well, so just wanted some confirmation that I am following the right path, since it's a lot of work to set up the db and the jpa project.

Comment: Quick note, before I forget: Look into SQLite. If your data doesn't need to be shared with other applications, it might be just what you need.

Comment: I agree with Lars that database is probably the best option, but remember that any calls you make to save or load data from the database is going to slow down any processing you have going on in memory. If your process depends on speed then it would probably make more sense to increase the amount of memory you've allocated to your program. Again I'm not clear where the data is coming from so I'm not sure how it should be saved. Anyway, to reduce the speed it takes to load the data you'll want to make sure you set up good keys and indexes so that you can query your dataset fast.